# Display Relative Time for just one day?

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs, dayjs

I use [dayJS](https://day.js.org/) and want to display relative time just for one day - 24 hour

is there way to customize fromNow() to just display for one day?

example

```
currentDate = 'Sun Aug 15 2021 15:03:09 GMT+0300';

oldDate = 'Fri Aug 13 2021 15:03:09 GMT+0300';

created_at = dayjs(currentDate).fromNow(true) => 17 min 2 sec // ok ✅ 

// if +=1 day
created_at = 
dayjs(oldDate).fromNow(true) => 2 day // hidden this one
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a workaround i tried :)
if there’s any other solution, let me know :)

```
 let acceptedDate = ['few seconds', 'minute', 'minutes', 'hour', 'hours'];
  let currentDate = dayjs();
  let targetedDay = created_at;// from api
  
  let currentRelativeTime = dayjs(targetedDay).from(currentDate, true);
  let timeArr = currentRelativeTime.split(' ');
  let isAcceptedDate = acceptedDate.some(item => timeArr.includes(item));
  console.log(isAcceptedDate);
```